# Subtracting value from data frame column: SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df`:

```
                    A           B           C
Date    
24/03/2014  -0.114726   -0.076779   -0.012105
25/03/2014  -0.118673   -0.078756   -0.008158
26/03/2014  -0.132919   -0.078067    0.006088
27/03/2014  -0.153581   -0.068223    0.026750
28/03/2014  -0.167744   -0.063045    0.040913
31/03/2014  -0.167399   -0.067346   -0.040568
01/04/2014  -0.166249   -0.068801    0.039418
02/04/2014  -0.160876   -0.077259    0.034045
03/04/2014  -0.156089   -0.090062    0.029258
04/04/2014  -0.161735   -0.079317   -0.034904
07/04/2014  -0.148305   -0.080767    0.021474
08/04/2014  -0.150812   -0.074792    0.023981
09/04/2014  -0.135339   -0.079736    0.008508
10/04/2014  -0.156345   -0.083574    0.029514
```

I am selecting the last value of column `B` using:

```
testValue=df['B'].iloc[-1]
```

in this case `testValue` equals `-0.083574`

Then I am trying to create a new column `'D'` into which I subtract `testValue` from all elements of column `'C`'.  So my desired output would look like:

```
                   A            B           C           D
    Date    
24/03/2014  -0.114726   -0.076779   -0.012105   -0.071469
25/03/2014  -0.118673   -0.078756   -0.008158   -0.075416
26/03/2014  -0.132919   -0.078067    0.006088   -0.089662
27/03/2014  -0.153581   -0.068223    0.026750   -0.110324
28/03/2014  -0.167744   -0.063045    0.040913   -0.124487
31/03/2014  -0.167399   -0.067346   -0.040568   -0.043006
01/04/2014  -0.166249   -0.068801    0.039418   -0.122992
02/04/2014  -0.160876   -0.077259    0.034045   -0.117619
03/04/2014  -0.156089   -0.090062    0.029258   -0.112832
04/04/2014  -0.161735   -0.079317   -0.034904   -0.048670
07/04/2014  -0.148305   -0.080767    0.021474   -0.105048
08/04/2014  -0.150812   -0.074792    0.023981   -0.107555
09/04/2014  -0.135339   -0.079736    0.008508   -0.092082
10/04/2014  -0.156345   -0.083574    0.029514   -0.113088
```

to subtract the `testValue` from column `'C'` I am using:

```
df['D']=testValue-df['C']
```

I however get the following copy warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  df['D']=testValue-df['C']
```

Why do I get the copy warning, and how can I fix it?

Comment: curiously, I did not have this warning. May I ask you about your pandas version? mine is `0.25.1`.

Comment: see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change selecting last values by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['D']=df.loc[df.index[-1], 'B']-df['C']
```

Or by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with position by `B` column by [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
df['D']=df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('B')]-df['C']
```

If still error, you can check how is created `df`, if there is some filtration need [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df = df1[df1['C'] > -0.3].copy()

df['D']=df.loc[df.index[-1], 'B']-df['C']
```

If you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df1`), and that Pandas does warning.

Answer (score 1):

The warning that you receive suggests that you are setting on a copy of a certain original data. As far as your data showed, there is no such a copy operation, especially in the line that you doubted: `df['D']=testValue-df['C']`.

I would bet that your `df` is a subset of something else. If that is the case, you can fix this by explicityly add `.copy()`at the end of the filter operation.

As an example, if we create a `df`from scratch, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`, we will not have your warning.
[image: No warning if df is initial data]

Now, if another dataframe is filter from `df`, and we do the same operation, we will have this warning.
[image: Have the SettingWithCopyWarning]

Finally, by adding `.copy()`, after filter, we will not have the warning anymore.

[image: no SettingWithCopyWarning warning]

Hope this helps. Kr

Answer (score -1):

If other solutions didn't work, this warning can be ignored using:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Run above spinnet once and no longer will receive `SettingWithCopyWarning`